# How can I "groupify" an elliptic curve over a non-field?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

The book *Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$* by David A. Cox contains the following definitions regarding an elliptic curve (by which he means an equation $y^2=4x^3-g_2x-g_3$ such that $\Delta=g_2^3-27g_3^2$ is invertible) over a general (commutative, unitary) ring $R$ in which $2$ and $3$ are invertible:

> Given an elliptic curve $E$ over $R$, we set
>   $$ E_0(R) = \{(x,y)\in R\times R:y^2=4x^3-g_2x-g_3\}\cup\{\infty\} \text. $$
>   The reason for the new notation is that $E_0(R)$ may *fail* to be a group!
>   [...]
>   **Using tools from algebraic geometry, one can define a superset $E(R)$ of $E_0(R)$ which is a group**, but we prefer to use $E_0(R)$ because it is easier to work with in practice.

(Emphasis mine.) My question is: What are these "tools from algebraic geometry" and how does one apply them to this problem?

Comment: Even if $R=\Bbb Z[1/2,1/3]$, ordinarily when you add two points, you need denominators to express the sum. Maybe he’s just referring to the projective plane over $R$, for putting $E$ into.

Comment: I think he just means that there is a general notion of an elliptic curve $E$ over a ring (even a scheme) and that it has the structure of a group (scheme over that base scheme).